# runnable jar file not runnable

Tags: java, jar, export

I'm trying to export my checkers program from Eclipse into a runnable jar file. I'm getting a jar file, but it doesn't run... It gives me cryptic error messages about classes that are not found. Isn't the point of the jar file that it contains all the classes it needs? I have no clue what to do now.

Here's what I get when I run the jar:

```
D:\Dokumente\workspace>java -jar Dame.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [[Lcheckers/Board$EmptySquare;
        at checkers.Board.<init>(Board.java:63)
        at checkers.Board.<init>(Board.java:49)
        at checkers.GameUI.main(GameUI.java:105)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: checkers.Board$EmptySquare
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 3 more
```

Maybe it helps to know that `EmptySquare` is an inner class of `Board`? 
What could be the problem? I tried both "extract required libraries" and "package required libraries" in the export wizard.

---

I also tried using `jar` from the command line, but it doesn't work as well. Here's what I did:

```
D:\Dokumente\workspace\Dame\bin\checkers>jar cvfe Dame.jar checkers.GameUI *.class
D:\Dokumente\workspace\Dame\bin\checkers>java -jar Dame.jar
Fehler: Hauptklasse checkers.GameUI.class konnte nicht gefunden oder geladen werden
(error: main class checkers.GameUI.class could not be found or loaded)
```

If I leave out the package name for the main class (`GameUI`), it also doesn't work:

```
D:\Dokumente\workspace\Dame\bin\checkers>jar cvfe Dame.jar GameUI *.class
D:\Dokumente\workspace\Dame\bin\checkers>java -jar Dame.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: GameUI (wrong name: checkers/GameUI)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

No clue.

The jar file content is:

```
D:\Dokumente\workspace\Dame\bin\checkers>jar tvf Dame.jar
     0 Thu Jan 09 01:05:26 CET 2014 META-INF/
    88 Thu Jan 09 01:05:26 CET 2014 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
   994 Thu Jan 09 00:14:30 CET 2014 Board$1.class
  1840 Thu Jan 09 00:14:30 CET 2014 Board$EmptySquare.class
   447 Thu Jan 09 00:14:30 CET 2014 Board$GamePiece.class
  4051 Thu Jan 09 00:14:30 CET 2014 Board$Piece.class
  4399 Thu Jan 09 00:14:30 CET 2014 Board$Queen.class
  8381 Thu Jan 09 00:14:30 CET 2014 Board.class
  2946 Thu Jan 09 00:14:30 CET 2014 Checkers.class
  2708 Thu Jan 09 00:14:30 CET 2014 CheckersAB.class
  4202 Thu Jan 09 00:14:30 CET 2014 CheckersABT.class
  2464 Thu Jan 09 00:14:30 CET 2014 CheckersMinMax.class
  1324 Thu Jan 09 00:14:30 CET 2014 CheckersPieces.class
   951 Thu Jan 09 00:14:30 CET 2014 GameState.class
   804 Thu Jan 09 00:14:30 CET 2014 GameUI$1.class
   663 Thu Jan 09 00:14:30 CET 2014 GameUI$2.class
  2535 Thu Jan 09 00:14:30 CET 2014 GameUI.class
   739 Thu Jan 09 00:14:30 CET 2014 GUIBoard$1.class
  6069 Thu Jan 09 00:14:30 CET 2014 GUIBoard.class
  3776 Thu Jan 09 00:14:30 CET 2014 Move.class
   607 Thu Jan 09 00:14:30 CET 2014 MoveComparator.class
   610 Thu Jan 09 00:14:30 CET 2014 NodeVal.class
  1078 Thu Jan 09 00:14:30 CET 2014 PlayCheckersAB.class
   356 Thu Jan 09 00:14:30 CET 2014 PlayCheckersABT.class
   357 Thu Jan 09 00:14:30 CET 2014 PlayCheckersMM.class
  2466 Thu Jan 09 00:14:30 CET 2014 PlayTournament.class
  1183 Thu Jan 09 00:14:30 CET 2014 Square.class
   241 Thu Jan 09 00:14:30 CET 2014 ZeroSumGame.class
```

Comment: Are all classes in the same package? Do you have more than one class with `main()` method?

Comment: @pm77: just updated the post. all classes are in packacke "checkers", except of course some libs (apache commons). There are more than 1 class files with a main method, but I told Eclipse which one is the right one. I also tried it with the jar-command. No luck.

Comment: Show your JAR's [manifest](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html).

Comment: @pm77: I thought the manifest was given inline with the "e" option (GameUI or checkers.GameUI, both don't work)? I don't have an extra file.

Comment: @divanov: I updated my question with the info.

Comment: You are showing `MANIFEST.MF` in the listing you added. Can you post the content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer. In post [eclipse doesn't compile the project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11878805/eclipse-doesnt-compile-the-project)
someone suggests to switch to a new workspace. I did that because besides the mysteriously non-working-jar file, Eclipse also didn't build my java files anymore. I switched to a new workspace, re-imported the project, and voila, the exported jar file is runnable!

Thanks for your efforts, especially to divanov!