# Eclipse doesn't clean or build any projects

Tags: eclipse, project, workspace

I'm running Eclipse Neon. Whenever I click on any of my projects and try to click clean or build it doesn't allow me to - it is greyed out. It doesn't matter if I make any changes to the code or do anything else, it never gives me the option to clean/build.

Comment: Are the projects Open? Are they any special kind of project, or just generic?

Comment: The projects are open. They are Java projects, POJO.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have **only general projects** without builders: **right-click on a project** and choose ***Properties***. In the *Properties for ...* dialog, **in *Builders* look if there any builder** listed. Without builders, your projects are probably configured incorrectly.

**Builders** (executed when project files are changed, e. g. incremental Java compiler) and **natures** (specifie which tooling is available) are set/stored in the `.project` file (which are hidden in the *Projects/Packages Explorer* view, but shown in the *Navigator* view and which can be edit with a text or XML editor). For example, the `.project` file of the plain Java project with the name and project folder *Foo* has the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>Foo</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

If available, you may try **right-click on a project and choose: *Configure > Configure and detect nested projects...***

Comment: Well you were right about the builders. There is no builder listed. However, when I click configure there is no option for configure and detect nested projects.